# Where brew install has pasted the path exactly

Tags: macos, homebrew, splinter

I was trying to use splinter which is a web-browsing package based on selenium.

Initially I attempted to run and got the error even though I have downloaded the chromedriver.

```
from splinter import Browser
browser = Browser()

os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

However I managed to run the code after `brew install chromedriver`.
I am curious of where exactly brew install has pasted the path into. I look into .bash_profile and didnt find any difference.

Comment: What do you mean by "brew install has pasted the path into"?

Comment: Basically I would like to know how to make the chromedriver work if I download it from the web, instead of running `brew install chromdriver`

Comment: Please use the edit button to add this in your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find out where the actual files are installed run `brew info chromedriver`. On my machine this gives the path

```
/usr/local/Cellar/chromedriver/2.33
```

This is not in my `$PATH`, but running `type` on the program tells us that

```
$ type chromedriver
chromedriver is /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

Which is in the path. And furthermore, that path is a symlink to the actual installation folder, which you can find out like this

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
lrwxr-xr-x  1 harald  admin  44 Nov 25 21:08 /usr/local/bin/chromedriver -> ../Cellar/chromedriver/2.33/bin/chromedriver
```

Answer (score 1):

I arrived here wondering where homebrew installed chromedriver. The answer is found by running [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/145481/290197) command:

```bash
brew info chromedriver
```

which tells that chromedriver is installed in this directory:

```
/usr/local/Caskroom/chromedriver/
```